# Run nvidia vulkan with prime-select = intel

Tags: nvidia, wayland, vulkan

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland window manager on a Dell laptop with intel and nvidia cards. I do prefer to use intel card for displaying staff for power saving.
However, I am using (and trying to develop) some applications using Vulkan API, and I want to unleash full power of Nvidia GPU.

So, what I have now: `prime-select query == intel`, `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
 == wayland`.

1. If I run `vulkaninfo`, it only detects intel card.
2. If I run

   `sudo modprobe nvidia
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-384:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   vulkaninfo`
    
   then, it tells `Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0"` and only detects intel card.
3. If I run the above, plus `unset DISPLAY`,
   `vulkaninfo` detects both cards correctly.
   Moreover, I successfully used both videocards to render something off-screen.

From the point 3 I can see that I can run nvidia using vulkan if I don't want to show anything on a screen.
Now, I want to do the same, while being able to render something onscreen
using intel card. Is that possible?

i.e. using vulkan API I can easily render stuff on nvidia card and transfer its results into intel card; but in my previous setting I unset `DISPLAY` environment, so the display surface is not available for intel card either. Can I workaround this somehow?